# find array key value and exlopde the same to key

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array (
    [Name] => Amjad Khan 
    [percentage] => 70.0 
    [Hobbies] => Array ( 
        [0] => reading 
        [1] => cricket 
        [2] => football 
        [3] => hockey
    ) 
)
```

I have the above array.

I need to filter the [Hobbies] like

```
[Hobbies]=>reading,cricket,football,hockey
```

Hobbies key is dynamic not static

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflox ! Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Edit your question and show us what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want, but try this:

```
$key = 'Hobbies';
$array[$key] = implode(',', $array[$key]);
```

Comment: Hobbies key is not static

Comment: I know, it is changed dynamically with the $key variable. Set the $key variable to whatever dynamic value 'Hobbies' is.

Comment: thanks a lot
but i edit the code
to check if(is_array($value)){ $array[$key] = implode(',', $array[$value]);}

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode` function

```
$arr = Array ( 'Name' => "Amjad Khan", 'percentage' => 70.0 ,'Hobbies' => Array ('reading','cricket','football','hockey' ) );
print_r($arr['Hobbies']);
$new = implode(',',$arr['Hobbies']);
echo $new;
```

Demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dacec2fbf86c62c95a2632aecf3583d608eeb097

Answer (score 0):

Try This!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
$arr = array(


   "Name" => Amjad,

   "percentage" => 70.0,

    "Hobbies" => array (
    "0" => reading,

     "1" => cricket, 

   "2" => football

    )         

  );



 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

  if($key == Hobbies){


 $arr[Hobbies] = implode(',',$value);

  }

       }

  echo '<pre>';

  print_r($arr);



 }
```

Comment: this is working but i use dynamic key here
how to check if any key found an array then implode that array for same key

Comment: if($key == $dynamicvariable){

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether Hobbies key exists or not, and then implode its values:

```
if (isset($array['Hobbies'])) {
    $array['Hobbies'] = implode(',', $array[$key]);
}
```